# hook pam_get_authtok_internal with ebpf

Tags: python, ebpf, pam, bpf, bcc

I try to do hook to pam_get_authtok_internal with ebpf and its not work

```
from bcc import BPF

# Define the BPF program code to print the password
bpf_text = """
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
int print_password (pam_handle_t *pamh, int item,const char **authtok, const char *prompt,unsigned int flags)
{
    char buf[256];
    bpf_probe_read_str(buf, sizeof(buf), (void *)authtok);
    bpf_trace_printk("Password: %s\\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
"""

b = BPF(text=bpf_text)

b.attach_uprobe(name=sudo_path,sym="pam_get_authtok_internal", fn_name="print_password")

def print_password(cpu, data, size):
    pid = b["passwords"].Key(data).value
    password = data + size - 1
    print(f"PID {pid} Password: {password.decode()}")
```

can someone help me with this please

Comment: `sudo_path` is not defined... what is this ?

Comment: also, `cpu` in the `print_password()` function is never used. did you mean to use it ?

Comment: finally,  how are you calling the function ?  it seems that there is missing code...   [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: its defined i dont put it there is:
sudo_path = "/usr/bin/sudo"

Comment: its say to me this error /virtual/main.c:5:21: error: unknown type name 'pam_handle_t'
int print_password (pam_handle_t *pamh, int item,const char **authtok, const char *prompt,unsigned int flags)

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to attach this `uprobe` because there is no such symbol in `sudo` binary. Before trying to attach `uprobe` or `uretprobe` try first checking which symbols available via `objdump -tT <file>` or `readelf -s <file>`.

The second issue is that the function `pam_get_authtok_internal` is [defined](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/libpam/pam_get_authtok.c#L82) as `static`, because of that, most likely it wouldn't appear in a symbol table of a proper file (which should be `libpam.so`). You can check which symbols available `objdump -tT /usr/lib/libpam.so`.

Doing debug build might fix this, also another option might be installing debug symbols and using information provided from debug symbols to pinpoint the correct location for this function. You can use `objdump -e` or `objdump -g` to get info from debug symbols, and then use this address instead of the symbol.